# Fourier Series pointwise convergence proof

Tags: convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis, pointwise-convergence

I have seen the proof of pointwise convergence of the Fourier Series using the Dirichlet kernel as:

$$
f(x)\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{D_n(t)dt}=f(x) 
$$

Since
$$
\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{D_n(t)dt}=1
$$
Though it is also true that:
$$
\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{0}{D_n(t)dt}=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}{D_n(t)dt}=\frac{1}{2}
$$
Since the Dirichlet-Fourier kernel is even.
Now in order to show:
$$\lim_{N \to \infty} f(x) - S_N(x) = 0$$
Where $S_n$ is the partial Fourier Series of $f(x)$ that can be written as:
$$
\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{f(t)D_N(x - t)dt}
$$
We have to make a change of variables so that we have a single variable $t$ in the kernel:
$$
-\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{x+\pi}^{x-\pi}{f(x-t)D_N(t)dt} = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{x-\pi}^{x+\pi}{f(x-t)D_N(t)dt}
$$
Now in the next step of the proof it would be said that $f(x)$ requires to be $2\pi$ periodic so that we can shift the above integral to any interval of length $2\pi$ (since the Dirichlet kernel is periodic, and the product of 2 such periodic functions is periodic):
$$
\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{x-\pi}^{x+\pi}{f(x-t)D_N(t)dt}=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{+\pi}{f(x-t)D_N(t)dt}
$$
Though it is entirely unclear why this step is essential in order for completion. And now we are going to be able to write up the difference of $f(x)$ and $S_N(x)$ as:
$$
f(x) - S_N(x) = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{(f(x) - f(x-t))D_N(t)dt}
$$
Now if we were to replace $D_N(t)$ with its single expression form, we would be able to apply the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma and show $f(x) - S_N(x) \nearrow 0$ given that $f$ is differentiable at $x$ (there are better proofs that show $S_N(x)$ approaches the average of left and right hand side limits at a point of discontinuity).
Now what my question is, if above we did NOT use the fact that $f(x)$ must be periodic in order for this to hold true:
$$
\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{x-\pi}^{x+\pi}{f(x-t)S_N(t)dt}=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{+\pi}{f(x-t)S_N(t)dt}
$$
Then why would not I be able to complete the proof saying that hey, $f(x)$ could be an arbitrary aperiodic function, and I do not even need to restrict the domain of $f(x)$ to the interval of integration?
So why can not I write:
$$
f(x) - S_N(x) = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{x-\pi}^{x+\pi}{(f(x) - f(x-t))D_N(t)dt}
$$
And apply the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma the same way?
In which very exact step of the proof I can not proceed without stating $f(x)$ is ought to be periodic if its domain is extended to the set of real numbers? Or even better question, what if I said I insist that $f(x)$ is an arbitrary function, then which part of the proof tells me that if I complete it then it will only be true between $-\pi$ and $\pi$?

Comment: Perhaps you can take a particular aperiodic function like $f(x)=x$ and look for the first statement in the proof which is false.

Comment: @aschepler you mean $f(x)\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{D_N(t)dt} = f(x)$ is false?

Comment: @aschepler sorry I forgot to add a multiplier of $\frac{1}{\pi}$

Comment: No, that statement is true. But $\lim_{N \to \infty} S_N(x) \neq f(x)$ when $f(x)=x$ and $|x|>\pi$. So at some point in between, the proof takes true statements and moves to a statement which is not true of $f(x)=x$. The reasoning at that point must rely on something which is not valid for $f(x)=x$, presumably that $f$ should be $2\pi$-periodic.

Comment: @aschepler so no other part of the proof reveals that $f(x)$ must periodic or if aperiodic then its domain is the interval of integration other than the fact that the Fourier Series is a periodic function?

Comment: @aschepler a rigorous explanation why in case of an aperiodic function the proof only works on the interval from $-\pi$ to $\pi$ is that because of the $2\pi$ periodicity of the Fourier Series the original equation can only be true on a given domain of $x$, and so any other equation derived from it can only be true on that one single domain?

Comment: Are you claiming that $$\lim_{N \to \infty} \int_{x-\pi}^{x+\pi} (f(x)-f(x-t)) D_N(t)\, dt = 0$$ Why would that be true?

Comment: @aschepler I was just asking whether the additional $x$ in the bounds of integration make a difference or on not. If yes, then why would not I be able to apply the Riemann Lebesgue Lemma to that expression?

Comment: The Riemann-Lebesgue lemma is about integrals on $\mathbb{R}^d$, so here $\int_{-\infty}^\infty$. You'd need to say how you want to apply it.

Comment: @aschepler for given value of $x$ the bounds of integration are fixed, so as far as I know if the integral of $g(t)$ converges on that interval then it should be applicable, as far as I know. What is the meaning of $\mathbb{R}^d$? I have never seen that notation.

Comment: @aschepler what I know about the Riemann Lebesgue Lemma is $\lim_{N \to \infty} \int_{a}^{b}{g(t)\cos(Nt)dt} = 0$ given that $\int_{a}^{b}{\mid g(t) \mid}<\infty$